# Does Gmail disallow choosing usernames for a new account that can cause confusion with existing ones?

Tags: gmail

Suppose there is already a Gmail user choosing the username (hence email address) as "abcdxyz2015", is it true that Gmail will disallow new users from choosing the username as "abcdxyz2o15" (notice the number '0' and the letter 'o')? If so, does this apply to "1" and "l" as well?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. This isn't documented anywhere, so the only practical way to find out is to try it, and you can do that as well as anybody else can.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, Google doesn't allow l to be interchanged with a 1, and an 0 to be interchanged with an o.

This doesn't seem to apply with all leet speak. An A can be interchanged with a 4 and so forth.